# Place \mbox around elements in a list

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, enumerate, enumitem

I am trying to achieve essentially the same effect as asked for [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270400/itemize-mbox-and-unwanted-line-break), except that I want to redefine `\item` to achieve the result automatically.  Specifically, I am trying to use an inline list with the `enumitem` package in which the items which would otherwise contain a line break are instead simply displayed on the next line.  Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Hello world!
\item Hello again!
\end{enumerate*}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Hello world!
\item \mbox{Hello again!}
\end{enumerate*}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}[1]{\olditem \mbox{#1}}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item Hello world!
\item Hello again!
\end{enumerate*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

The first result is what happens by default, the second result is a correct fix with the `\mbox` placed directly after `\item`, and the third result is my failed attempt to automate the `\mbox` by redefining `\item`.

How do I correctly automate the placement of the `\mbox` around every element in the list, or otherwise, how do I prevent this mid-item line breaking.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Macro to capture until end-of-line as argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127005/5764)

Comment: The 'correct fix' is typographically horrible, though. Unless you are going to apply `\raggedright` to the paragraph, this seems designed to produce ugliness.